# garmin gdl 52 vs foreflight sentry?

Tags: ads-b

Does it make sense to go with a garmin ADS-B with sirius XM or a regular foreflight sentry ADS-B? I am using garmin pilot but do not mind shifting to foreflight.
On the flipside, i read that the Satellite ADS-B is better than the line of sight ADS-B. Any recommendations? Which one is better?

Comment: To be clear, you are talking about ADSB-IN. Satellite ADSB is a Canada thing aimed at picking up ADSB-OUT signals with fewer ground stations.

Comment: I think i figured it out. I am talking about ADS-B-IN. And i went with the GDL 52 due to the satellite weather capability.That seems superior to regular weather and i will eventually go commercial and then airline some day. So until then, the GDL 52 is my better option.